# Change the setting value of the config file through a regular expression

Tags: regex, apache

I want to change the following settings using regular expression.

1.

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24" <<-- c:/Apache24
=> \s*SRVROOT "\s*(.*")
```

2.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 <<- not change
Listen 80 <-- 80
=> [^\S\r\n].[^#]Listen \s*([0-9].*)
```

But the regular expression I used is not working properly.

How do we must be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find and replace the value between the double quotes for the first example, you could use 2 capturing groups instead to capture what you want to keep and match what you want to replace.

Match what is between the double quotes using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^"]+` (because  using `.*` can also match a double quote)

```
^(Define\s*SRVROOT ")[^"]+(")
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(Define\s*SRVROOT ")` Capture **group 1** Match `Define SRVROOT "`
- `[^"]+` Match 1+ times any char except a `"`
- `(")` Capture **group 2** match a `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJns7z/1)

In the replacement use those 2 capturing groups for example `$1CHANGED$2`

---

For the second example, if you don't want to match `#Listen` but do want to match `Listen` you could either use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string or use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` to assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char.

```
^(Listen\s*)[0-9]+\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(Listen\s*)` Capture in **group 1** matching Listen and 0+ times a whitespace char
- `[0-9]+\b` Match 1+ digits and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jUs1VL/1)

In the replacement use the only capturing group for example `$1 8080`

Comment: Oh, So Thank U~ :)